# How to comapare the webelement list to String

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

```
List<String> unitType = new ArrayList<String>();
unitType = getUnitTypeNumber();
String leaseTermsunitNumber = getLeaseTermUnitNumer().getText();
String unitNumber = leaseTermsunitNumber.trim().substring(leaseTermsunitNumber.indexOf(":") + 1);

System.out.println("unitType.toString()"+unitType.toString());

compareList(unitNumber,unitType.toString(), "compare unit number ");
```

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

**First**

Your code does not match what you're asking, since there is no `WebElement` list.

**Second**

```
List<String> unitType = new ArrayList<String>();
unitType = getUnitTypeNumber();
```

This does not make sense. You instantiate new `ArrayList` object assigning it to `unitType` and then reassign another object to that reference right away. This should look like:

```
List<String> unitType = getUnitTypeNumber();
```

**Third**

Comparing a list to a string does not make sense since `List` conversion to a `String` depends on how `toString()` method is implemented. If you have a list of `WebElement` objects you probably should have a `List` of String objects. Hence, iterating through the `WebElements` you take text value from them and compare to the corresponding `String` object from the `List` of `Strings`

Answer (score 0):

Get the text for each element in the list and compare it with whatever string you want.
Use getattribute method on each element.